# Why do my total cart price not compute correctly?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a school project of designing an ecommerce webpage. I am new to this and is facing some problem at the shopping cart check out portion. Would really appreciate any help from you guys ! :)

There's already an item (let's call it item A) in the cart every time the webpage reload. I am able to get a correct total price computation for every increasing quantity of item A in the cart. However, when I add another item into the cart and increase the quantity of the newly added item , the total price won't update. I also noticed that when I increase the quantity of item A when there is other items in the cart. The total price = (quantity * total amount) in the cart instead of computing just the price of item.

Here's the js, css and html code:

```js
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
  ready()
}

function ready() {
  var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-1');
  console.log(removeCartItemButtons)
  for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
  }

  var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
  for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
    var input = quantityInputs[i]
    input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
  }

  var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-2')
  for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = addToCartButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
  }

  document.getElementsByClassName
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
  var buttonClicked = event.target
  buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
  updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
  var input = event.target
  if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
    input.value = 1
  }
  updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
  var button = event.target
  var shopItem = button.parentElement
  var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
  var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
  var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
  console.log(title, price, imageSrc)
  addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc)
  updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
  var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
  cartRow.classList.add()
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
  var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
  for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
    if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
      alert('This item is already been added to the cart')
      return
    }
  }
  var cartRowContents = `  
                 <div class="cart-items">
                  <table class="cart-row">
                   <tr>
                    <td>
                    <div class="cart-info">
                       <img class="cart-item-image"src="${imageSrc}" >
                       <div>
                           <p class="cart-item-title">${title}</p>
                           <small>Price: ${price}</small>
                           <br>
                           <button class="btn-1" type="button">Remove</button>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </td>
               <td><input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" min="1" value="1"></td>
                <td
                class="cart-price">${price}
               </td >
                </tr>
                </table>
           </div>`
  cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
  cartItems.append(cartRow)
  cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-1')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
  cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}


function updateCartTotal() {
  var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
  var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
  var total = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    var cartRow = cartRows[i]
    var quantityElement = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
    var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
    var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerHTML.replace('$', ''))
    var quantity = quantityElement.value
    total = total + (price * quantity)
  }
  total = (Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
  document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerHTML = '$' + total
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

p {
  color: black;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.col-2 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  min-width: 400px;
}

.col-2 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.col-2 h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ff523b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.col-4 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.col-4 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.small-container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: black
}

.title::after {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  width: 80px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.col-4:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.btn-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ff523b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}


/*------footer-----*/

.footer {
  background: #000;
  color: #8a8a8a;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 40px 0 20px;
}

.footer-col-1 {
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-col-1 img {
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer p {
  color: #8a8a8a;
}


/*------cart-----*/

.cart-page {
  margin: 80px auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.cart-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

th {
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ff523b;
  font-weight: normal;
}

td {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  width: 1px;
}

td input {
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: right;
}

td a {
  color: #ff523b;
  font-size: 10px;
}

td img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.btn-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ff523b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.total-price {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.total-price table {
  border-top: 3px solid #ff523b;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

th:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-purchase {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ff523b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-purchase:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.btn-1:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.cart-item {
  width: 60%;
}


/*------------ account page --------------*/

.account-page {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.form-container {
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form-container span {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-btn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-container form {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 130;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

form input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

form .btn {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

form .btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#LoginForm {
  left: -300px;
}

#RegForm {
  left: 0;
}

form a {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#Indicator {
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  background: #ff523b;
  margin-top: 8px;
  height: 3px;
  transform: translateX(100px);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Internet Security PBIL</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="store.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="yeet/yeet.jpg" width="80px">
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="store.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="account.php">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <h1>Good Sport <br>Good game!</h1>
        <p>Come buy our good items now!</p>
        <a href="" class="btn">Explore Now</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <img src="yeet/image1.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-------- products -------->
  <div class="small-container">
    <h2 class="title">Shirt</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="shop-item-image" src="yeet/product-1.jpg">
        <h4 class="shop-item-title">Red</h4>
        <p class="shop-item-price">$10.00</p>
        <button class="btn-2">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="shop-item-image" src="yeet/product-2.jpg">
        <h4 class="shop-item-title">Blue</h4>
        <p class="shop-item-price">$20.00</p>
        <button class="btn-2">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="shop-item-image" src="yeet/product-3.jpg">
        <h4 class="shop-item-title">Green</h4>
        <p class="shop-item-price">$30.00</p>
        <button class="btn-2">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="shop-item-image" src="yeet/product-4.jpg">
        <h4 class="shop-item-title">Yellow</h4>
        <p class="shop-item-price">$40.00</p>
        <button class="btn-2">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="title">Shorts</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="shop-item-image" src="yeet/product-5.jpg">
        <h4 class="shop-item-title">1 printed t-shirt</h4>
        <p class="shop-item-price">$50.00</p>
        <button class="btn-2">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="shop-item-image" src="yeet/product-6.jpg">
        <h4 class="shop-item-title">2 printed t-shirt</h4>
        <p class="shop-item-price">$60.00</p>
        <button class="btn-2">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="shop-item-image" src="yeet/product-7.jpg">
        <h4 class="shop-item-title">3 printed t-shirt</h4>
        <p class="shop-item-price">$70.00</p>
        <button class="btn-2">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="shop-item-image" src="yeet/product-8.jpg">
        <h4 class="shop-item-title">4 printed t-shirt</h4>
        <p class="shop-item-price">$80.00</p>
        <button class="btn-2">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!----- cart items details ----->
  <section class="small-container cart-page">
    <h2 class="title">Cart</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="cart-item">Product</th>
        <th class="cart-qunatity">Quantity</th>
        <th class="cart-price">Subtotal</th>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="cart-items">
      <table class="cart-row">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="cart-info">
              <img class="cart-item-image" src="yeet/buy-1.jpg">
              <div>
                <p class="cart-item-title">Red Printed Tshirt</p>
                <small>Price: $50.00</small>
                <br>
                <button class="btn-1" type="button">Remove</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td><input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" min="1" value="1"></td>
          <td><span class="cart-price">$50.10</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <!---       <table>
                   <tr class="cart-row">
                    <td>
                    <div class="cart-info">
                       <img class="cart-item-image" src="yeet/buy-2.jpg" >
                       <div>
                           <p class="cart-item-title">Red Printed Tshirt</p>
                           <small>Price: $80.0</small>
                           <br>
                           <button class="btn-1" type="button">Remove</button>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </td>
               <td><input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" min="1" value="1"></td>
                       <td class="cart-price">$80.50</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
           </div> --->

    <div class="total-price">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="cart-total-title">Total</td>
          <td class="cart-total-price">$50.50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-purchase" type="button">Purchase</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-----footer----->
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="footer-col-1">
        <p>Products brought to you by Yeet!</p>
        <img src="yeet/yeet.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Thank you guys for your help!
(ps: please ignore the naming of my items as is not finalize yet haha,cheers!)

Comment: in the loop you get prize and quantity of item always with index 0 instead of i

Comment: may i know which loop you're referring too ? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it was hard to see, so I made an answer of it:

you used once cartItemContainer instead of cartRow, so you couldn't understand my comment... :-)

```
var quantityElement = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input') [0]  <- should be cartRow
var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! I didn't noticed the error, it works now ! Cheers :)

Comment: Glad I could help... It's often the problem with your own code. You see the intention, not what is there...